# How to "clone" Lists of Objects without dereferencing the items themselves

Tags: java, list, copy, clone, dereference

I have 2 ArayLists: ArrayList 1 and ArrayList 2;
Basically, i need to have something like ArrayList 2 = new ArrayList(1); but if i change the second list in any way, the first list should remain the same, but if i change an item from the second list, it should also modify in the first. I've tried using clones, constructors that would just copy the attributes of one object and create another, and add that in the second list, but every time i change the second list, the first one changes also.
So, how could i just have 2 lists, that at first have the same items, in the same order, but themselves are totally different? Just adding the each item from the first list to the second doesn't work..
Example:

```
ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>():
list1.add(obj1);
list1.add(obj2);
ArrayList<Object) list2 = new ArrayList<Object>(list1);
list2.remove(0);
```

What i want is to be able to modify list2 (list2.remove(0)) but i need list1 to remain unmodified, so list1.size()!=list2.size(). Also: i need that obj1 from list1 to be the same to obj1 from the list2.

Comment: This is really unclear.  Please add some examples to illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>():

Comment: That doesn't help explain what kind of behaviour you want in terms of element modifications.

Comment: So your lists should contain the same objects at beginning and the state and each list should behave by its own regardless the states modification on the objects they contain?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, and also, modifying one list (removing, adding item) would not modify the other one.

Comment: This works with primitives, for example if Object were an Integer, but how can i make it work with other types?

Comment: The code above does what you want. Don't confuse modifying the list, and modifying an object inside the list though. If you want modifications of the objects inside the second list to not affect the first one, then you need to copy every object, and not just the list.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you state. Your current code should work for any kind of object reference it stores. What's the exact problem here?

Comment: The exact problem is that at first, list1 and list2 has a size of 130. I remove an item from list2 and when i check again both list1 and list 2 have size 129 when list1 should be 130 and only list2 should be 129. This is in android, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user3102515: that's incorrect, you're doing something wrong in your test (like printing the length of the same list twice, for example).

Comment: Apparently the original code works. But i still haven't fixed my problem. I had a constructor like this: 

    public Object(ArrayList<Obj> lst){  
  list = new ArrayList<Obj>(lst);   
 } 

And a second method

    public void remove(){
    list.remove(2);
    Log.d("Size of list", Integer.toString(list.size());
    Log.d("size of lst", Integer.toString(lst.size());
    Log.d("Equals", Boolean.toString(list.equals(lst)));
    }

where lst is a static ArrayList from another class. It always returned 129, 129, true. Would having a static argument to the constructor matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but if i change the second list in any way, the first list should remain the same

So just copy the references into a new list. There are constructors for that.

> but if i change an item from the second list, it should also modify in the first.

See above.

> I've tried using clones, constructors that would just copy the attributes of one object and create another and add that in the second list

That's what you *don't* want to do. You want the original references in both lists.

> but every time i change the second list, the first one changes also

Not possible. If you did want you describe, the two lists and their contents are completely independent. In any case this is the wrong approach. This also constitutes dereferencing the original objects, which you said you didn't want to do.

> Just adding each item from the first list to the second doesn't work

Yes it does. I suggest you have confused yourself with all these alternatives.